# Strapi 4.1.5 email plugin configuration

Tags: email, strapi

Unable to change email configuration. I specify the settings according to the instructions.

- Restarted the server.
- Removed cache and node_modules

In any case, the default plugin configuration is used.

node v14.18.2
strapi 4.1.5

```
{
  "name": "strapi-test",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.1.5",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.1.5",
    "@strapi/provider-email-nodemailer": "^4.1.5",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.1.5",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.2"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "87e9d8e3-8c82-4c8e-8de4-990c2b729be4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.x.x <=16.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**SOLUTION https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/12919#issuecomment-1075954840**

Comment: solution https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/12919#issuecomment-1075954840

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case anyone looking for the answer for this.
[image: derrick m, discord]

like derick says, in strapi v4 the provider and providerOptions need to be wrapped inside config.
like this

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    // ...
    email: {
      config: {
        provider: 'nodemailer',
        providerOptions: {
          host: env('SMTP_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
          port: env('SMTP_PORT', 465),
          auth: {
            user: env('SMTP_USERNAME', 'email@gmail.com'),
            pass: env('SMTP_PASSWORD', 'password'),
          },
        },
        settings: {
          defaultFrom: 'email@gmail.com',
          defaultReplyTo: 'email@gmail.com',
        },
      },
    },
    // ...
  });
```

Comment: that interests me.  Where should this be defined ?